# Why are all Drupal mails going to spam folder wheter it is reset password mail, account activation e-mail etc.?

Tags: hooks, emails

All the e-mails from my site are going but they are going to spam folder, whether its the Drupal system generated mails like reset password mail, account activation mail etc.
 How can I prevent that?

Comment: What does the algorithm you use to decide if something is spam have to "say" about it? What reason it gives? if it is the case of your site having low reputation and domain is  known to be reported as spammer earlier, it is not really a Drupal question, for example.

Comment: Hi Mołot, whenever any user performs password recovery, they get e-mail into their g-mail (suppose they are using g-mail) spam folder, this justifies that the mail is spam.

Comment: If you are asking us why Google think you are spammer, then sorry, no way for us to know. Try to ask Google. Webmaster Tools would be something worth to have, even if not directly related to email. If user gets message like *"Why this message is in spam? Because ..."*, there is usually a reason and link to Google help page. Share them. We need to know the **reason**. Repeating that it does happen is not useful. You told it. OK. Once was enough. Now tell us direct **why**, and we might be able to tell you how to fix it. Maybe.

Comment: Here i am using 'Google' just as an example to make my question clear to you, Hope you understood the question correctly now ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Mohit We can't speculate as to why your emails are being marked as spam. Perhaps it's the content, perhaps it's the domain, perhaps it's something else. Unless you can narrow this down to a specific problem with Drupal, you're not going to be able to get help for the issue here. It's not a matter of understanding what you're asking or not, simply that this isn't the right place to ask for help with non-Drupal related subjects. The fact that your website is instigating the email doesn't mean the problem is related to Drupal in any way (it's 99.99% certain not to be a Drupal problem)

Comment: Thanks Clive, I really don't know about this issue, This is the first time i got such issue with drupal 7, being a developer I posted this question here, I have already conveyed/passed the issue details to my server technical team, hopefully they might come with a solution.
Thanks for being concerned Clive.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a technical sure fire solution. There can't be a sure fire answer either, because spam detection algorithms are different, even if the recipient mail server had same software, per-account activity and a lot of factors can be used to decide whether the email is spam or not.

There are some steps I take for every site before going them live. 
The obvious one is to not send spam content in first place, but other than the content itself, there are other ways to convince the recipient you are not spamming.

1. Setup SPF records for your domain. The spec is easy to understand, and there are tools to generate the record too. You need to make sure you only send emails from the correct IP addresses only.
2. Install MimeMail module. This is probably overlooked, but Drupal default mail class sends emails using php's mail() function directly. Mimemail does this too, but it adds extra headers and better mime information. All modules using drupal_mail to send emails will be instantly compatible with the module. 
   Think about going to a meeting with a basic dress vs a complete suit.

Mimemail trick is the most effective one I've tested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ayesh K. and sorry for replying late, this did not solve my problem, I have created many sites in drupal but this is the first time I got such issue. Any more help / suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks